# How to make a keyboard shortcut for Environments at LyX?

Tags: lyx, environments

If I'm writing an environment at the preamble at LyX.
For example:

```
\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
```

But, I try to avoid from write each time:

```
\begin{example}
...
\end{example}
```

(At LyX, you to do it with `ctrl+l`, for each part...)

So, there is a way to put this environment with keyboard shortcut? or something else....

I took the exaple from here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Environments

Thank you!

Comment: You should create your own layout so that you can select your environment from the LyX layout menu (the upper-left thing that usually says "Standard"). You should read through Help > Customization, especially the parts on layouts. It is a long, dry read, but it will really take your LyXing to the next level.

Comment: Thank you!! @scottkosty - Can you explain me little bit more, I saw this document, but it's not clear to me how to put it at layout file....

Comment: It looks like Section 5 is the one that you should read. For example, you want LatexType equal to Environment and LatexName equal to example. And probably you also have to set a counter somehow. I don't actually know what to do. Every time I want to do something like this, I have to reread Section 5. Good luck!